# Javascript ROT13 Function working only partially

Tags: javascript, caesar-cipher, rot13

My ROT13 JS function works fine for the most part, but some of the characters just come out wrong, e.g. `HELLO` comes back with `U,R,Y,Y,\`.

Could somebody please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

P.s I'm doing the freeCodeCamp Caesars Cipher Challenge.

```js
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  var stringArray = str.split("");
  var stringArray2 = [];
  var stringArray3 = [];
  for( var i in stringArray){
    var y = stringArray[i].charCodeAt();
    y += 13;
    stringArray2.push(y);
  }
  for (var u in stringArray2){
    var x = String.fromCharCode(stringArray2[u]);
    stringArray3.push(x);
  }
  var transformed = stringArray3.join().toString();
  return transformed;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
console.log(rot13("HELLO"));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide an example of the function not working, like input:...., expected:...., but got: .....

Comment: Of course, sorry for not including it in the entry in the first place!

"HELLO" comes back with " U, R, Y, Y, \"

Comment: Thanks! Ok, two problems: first (minor): you need `.join('')`, not just `.join()` to get rid of commas. Second (major): this thing is called "rot" for a reason: when `y+13` is greater than `Z` it should *rotate* and start from the beginning, that is, `Z + 13` should give `A + 12` etc.

Comment: I get it, now that I think about it this way it looks so obvious! Guess I was too deep in thoughts about other aspects of the problem! Thank you, that really clarifies what happened!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer you an alternative to your ROT13 function.

The alternative that I'm proposing is just a particular usage of a regular Caesar Cipher algorithm – a very simple form of encryption, in which each letter in the original message is shifted to the left or right by a certain number of positions.

To decrypt the message we simply shift back the letters the same number of positions.

Example:

- JAVASCRIPT becomes MDYDVFULSW if we shift all letters by 3 positions
- MDYDVFULSW turns back to JAVASCRIPT if we shift back all letters by 3 positions.

If after shifting a letter goes outside the range of letters, then the letter is wrapped around in alphabet. Example: Letter Z becomes C if is shifted by 3 positions.

This “wrap-around” effect means use of modulo. In mathematical terms, the above can be expressed as this:

En(x) = (x + n) mod 26

Dn(x) = (x – n) mod 26

Trying to implement this algorithm in JavaScript without the use of a proper modulo operator will produce either incorrect results or a very cryptic and difficult to understand code.

The biggest problem is that JavaScript doesn't contain a modulo operator. The % operator is just the reminder of the division - not modulo. However, it is pretty easy to implement modulo as a custom function:

```
// Implement modulo by replacing the negative operand 
// with an equivalent positive operand that has the same wrap-around effect
function mod(n, p)
{
    if ( n < 0 )
        n = p - Math.abs(n) % p;

    return n % p;
}
```

There are other ways of implementing modulo... if you are interested you can consult this [article](http://www.codeavenger.com/2017/05/19/JavaScript-Modulo-operation-and-the-Caesar-Cipher.html).

By using the mod function defined above, the code expresses the mathematical equation identically:

```
// Function will implement Caesar Cipher to
// encrypt / decrypt the msg by shifting the letters
// of the message acording to the key
function encrypt(msg, key)
{
    var encMsg = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++)
    {
        var code = msg.charCodeAt(i);

        // Encrypt only letters in 'A' ... 'Z' interval
        if (code >= 65 && code <= 65 + 26 - 1)
        {
            code -= 65;
            code = mod(code + key, 26);
            code += 65;
        }

        encMsg += String.fromCharCode(code);
    }

    return encMsg;
}
```

To encode using ROT13 ... is now just a matter of choosing the appropriate key as indicated by algorithm name.

Answer (score 0):

```
function rot13(str) {
  str = str.split("");
  function a(item){
    let result;
    if (item.charCodeAt()>=65&&item.charCodeAt()<78){
      result= String.fromCharCode(item.charCodeAt()+13); 
    }
    else if(item.charCodeAt()>=78&&item.charCodeAt()<=95){
      result= String.fromCharCode(item.charCodeAt()-13);
    }
    else{
      result = item;
    }
    return result;
  }
  str = str.map(item=>a(item)).join("");
  console.log(str);
  return str;
}

rot13("GUR DHVPX OEBJA SBK WHZCF BIRE GUR YNML QBT.");
```